# Using helper functions inside trigger functions

Tags: c#, function, triggers, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use helper function in order to make the function pause for few seconds but it doesn't execute the wait function.

That's the code I've been using:

Code:

```
public class Triggers : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerator wait(float seconds) {
        Debug.Log("In wait");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        Debug.Log("after wait");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider _collider)
    {
        Debug.Log("Destroy");
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Before wait");
        wait(5);
        Debug.Log("activate");
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by just deactivating the child object which is the actual "physical" object I wanted to hide on collision with the invisible parent object.So now the parent object stays active, counting the time and the physical object "Cube" dis appears and reappears after n seconds.

```
   public class Triggers : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator wait (float seconds)
    {
        Debug.Log ("In wait");
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find ("Cube");
        go.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        Debug.Log ("after wait");
        go.SetActive (true);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider _collider)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Destroy");
        Debug.Log ("Before wait");
        StartCoroutine (wait (5));
        Debug.Log ("activate");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
StartCoroutine(wait(5));
```

instead of simply "wait(5)".

This is the way coroutines work in C#, if I remember well...

Comment: It gives me the error that Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object is inactive. Any other solution ?

Comment: If this doesn't do what you expected, you could try to attach the script to another `Monobehaviour`, in your object's hierarchy.

Comment: What happens if you attach the script to an empty parent `GameObject`, and activate/deactivate your `gameObject` which would be moved as a child of this empty object ?

Comment: I solved the problem , I'll be able to post the solution in 2 hours . Thank you for the help !